# Converting text to small number javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a real time chat system. I am sending messages and saving them to the database. But before saving  the message into database i need to encrypt it with using NTRU for Integers algorithm. In order to use this algorithm i have to convert text into numbers. I already tried to convert to ASCII code but its creating too big number for algorithm. Is there any way to convert text into small numbers? Saving into database with `parent.send_message(chat_input.value)`

```
 create_chat(){

  var parent = this;

  var title_container = document.getElementById('title_container')
  var title = document.getElementById('title')
  title_container.classList.add('chat_title_container')

  title.classList.add('chat_title')

  var chat_container = document.createElement('div')
  chat_container.setAttribute('id', 'chat_container')

  var chat_inner_container = document.createElement('div')
  chat_inner_container.setAttribute('id', 'chat_inner_container')

  var chat_content_container = document.createElement('div')
  chat_content_container.setAttribute('id', 'chat_content_container')

  var chat_input_container = document.createElement('div')
  chat_input_container.setAttribute('id', 'chat_input_container')

  var chat_input_send = document.createElement('button')
  chat_input_send.setAttribute('id', 'chat_input_send')
  chat_input_send.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  chat_input_send.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i>`

  var chat_input = document.createElement('input')
  chat_input.setAttribute('id', 'chat_input')
  
  

  chat_input.setAttribute('maxlength', 11)

  chat_input.placeholder = `${parent.get_name()}. Say hello..`
  chat_input.onkeyup  = function(){
    if(chat_input.value.length > 0){
      chat_input_send.removeAttribute('disabled')
      chat_input_send.classList.add('enabled')
      chat_input_send.onclick = function(){
        chat_input_send.setAttribute('disabled', true)
        chat_input_send.classList.remove('enabled')
        if(chat_input.value.length <= 0){
          return
        }
    
        parent.create_load('chat_content_container')
  

        chat_input.value  = chat_input.value.toLocaleUpperCase()
        
        parent.send_message(chat_input.value)

        chat_input.value = ''

        chat_input.focus()
      }
```

Comment: ASCII?! Then what happens if someone sends unicode chars in your "real time chat system"?

Comment: That was the one solution that i found as a beginner to javascript o.O if you have other solution i am open the solution?

Comment: If you're looking to convert alphanumeric plus some punctuation to a number, you're already looking at 62+ characters which means you need at minimum 6 bits per character.  So, a 20 character text message will yield 64^20 combinations which is a 36 digit decimal number.  What specific range do you mean by "small numbers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with this code

```
// Vocabulary
        let vocabulary  = new Array();{
          vocabulary[10] = "A";
          vocabulary[11] = "B";
          vocabulary[12] = "C";
          vocabulary[13] = "D";
          vocabulary[14] = "E";
          vocabulary[15] = "F";
          vocabulary[16] = "G";
          vocabulary[17] = "H";
          vocabulary[18] = "I";
          vocabulary[19] = "J";
          vocabulary[20] = "K";
          vocabulary[21] = "L";
          vocabulary[22] = "M";
          vocabulary[23] = "N";
          vocabulary[24] = "O";
          vocabulary[25] = "P";
          vocabulary[26] = "Q";
          vocabulary[27] = "R";
          vocabulary[28] = "S";
          vocabulary[29] = "T";
          vocabulary[30] = "U";
          vocabulary[31] = "V";
          vocabulary[32] = "W";
          vocabulary[33] = "X";
          vocabulary[34] = "Y";
          vocabulary[35] = "Z";
          vocabulary[36] = " ";
          vocabulary[37] = "a";
          vocabulary[38] = "b";
          vocabulary[39] = "c";
          vocabulary[40] = "d";
          vocabulary[41] = "e";
          vocabulary[42] = "f";
          vocabulary[43] = "g";
          vocabulary[44] = "h";
          vocabulary[45] = "i";
          vocabulary[46] = "j";
          vocabulary[47] = "k";
          vocabulary[48] = "l";
          vocabulary[49] = "m";
          vocabulary[50] = "n";
          vocabulary[51] = "o";
          vocabulary[52] = "p";
          vocabulary[53] = "q";
          vocabulary[54] = "r";
          vocabulary[55] = "s";
          vocabulary[56] = "t";
          vocabulary[57] = "u";
          vocabulary[58] = "v";
          vocabulary[59] = "w";
          vocabulary[60] = "x";
          vocabulary[61] = "y";
          vocabulary[62] = "z";
          vocabulary[63] = "!";
        }

        // Converting Text into numbers
        var number = "";
        for(var z = 0 ; z < chat_input.value.length ; z++)
        {
          for(var i = 10 ; i < 64 ; i++) {
            if(chat_input.value.charAt(z) == vocabulary[i]) {
              var test = i;
              test = test.toString();
              number = number + test;
            }
          }
        }

        // Seperating numbers into array
        var numbers = new Array() ;
        var index = 0 ;

          while(number.length !== 0) {
            if (number.length == 3) {
              numbers[index] = number.substring(0, 3);
              number = number.substring(3,number.length);
            } else if (number.length == 2) {
              numbers[index] = number.substring(0, 2);
              number = number.substring(2,number.length);
            } else if (number.length == 1) {
              numbers[index] = number.substring(0, 1);
              number = number.substring(1,number.length);
            } else
              numbers[index] = number.substring(0, 4);
              number = number.substring(4,number.length);
            index++;
          }


          //Encrpyting numbers and getting cipher text
          var indexofe = 0 ;
          var ciphertextz = new Array();
          while(indexofe !== numbers.length) {
            ciphertextz[indexofe] = parent.Encrypt(numbers[indexofe]);
            indexofe++;
          }
```